# Flutter navigation menu

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm starting out with Flutter and I'd like to make an application similar to this one here: https://github.com/fluttermapp/flutter-ui-panel-dashboard

The app works fine, the only problem I have is getting the navigation to work. I see that there is a drawer set up, but unfortunately I have no idea how to set up routing for other pages.
https://github.com/fluttermapp/flutter-ui-panel-dashboard/blob/main/lib/widget_tree.dart#L72

Could you please advise me how to set up the routing via the drawer?

Comment: You can check this https://github.com/fluttermapp/flutter-ui-panel-dashboard/blob/main/lib/pages/drawer/drawer_page.dart ..... This is the definition of that drawer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution via go_router:

https://pub.dev/packages/go_router